# Symfony 3 / create own framework tutorial

Tags: symfony, controller

Folowing the tutorial:
https://symfony.com/doc/current/create_framework/templating.html
I met some logical "jump over" on how a body of anonymus function from a route, can be called only by passing the name of the route with a help of the request attribute ?

```
'_controller'=> function ($request) {
```

found in a route declaration:

```
$routes->add('hello', new Routing\Route('/hello/{name}', array(
    'name' => 'World',
    '_controller'=> function ($request) {
        return render_template($request);
    }
)));
```

and

```
$response = call_user_func($request->attributes->get('_controller'),
```

found in a front controller:

```
try {
    $request->attributes->add($matcher->match($request->getPathInfo()));
    $response = call_user_func($request->attributes->get('_controller'), 
$request);
} catch (Routing\Exception\ResourceNotFoundException $e) {
    $response = new Response('Not Found', 404);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $response = new Response('An error occurred', 500);
}
```

Would anyone be willing to explain how does it work ?

Thx in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Ok it's clear now, it's the matcher who does the necessary job.

```
$matcher->match($request->getPathInfo())
```

in

```
try {
    $request->attributes->add($matcher->match($request->getPathInfo()));
    $response = call_user_func($request->attributes->get('_controller'), 
$request);
} catch (Routing\Exception\ResourceNotFoundException $e) {
    $response = new Response('Not Found', 404);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $response = new Response('An error occurred', 500);
}
```